# Как проигнорировать строки комментариев в git

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Как проигнорировать строки комментариев в git, а именно в intellij idea или android studio? Пишу комментарии для себя в коде,  но не хочу что бы они пушились в git.

Answer (score 3):

Никак Вы их не проигнорируете. Если git отслеживает изменения файла, он отслеживает их все, включая комментирование кода.